# Model Inference on non-parametric models

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, inference

I have a multi-variable regression problem where I am trying to both:

1. Obtain good predictions (small RMSE) on out of sample data
2. Perform model inference in order to understand the impact of individual variables

So far I have experimented with a linear regression (LR) model and a gradient boosted tree model (GBM). The GBM model outperforms the LR model significantly on my test set in terms of RMSE, however being a non-parametric model, the standard methods of statistical inference are not available.

To perform model inference I was planning on doing the following instead: for a test data sample $i$, perturb the predictor variable of interest $x^{(i)}_k$ by $\delta$ and calculate the prediction:
$$\hat{y}_\delta^{(i)} = f(x^{(i)}_1,...,x^{(i)}_k+\delta,...,x^{(i)}_p)$$

Then I could calculate the difference in target variable $\epsilon^{(i)} = y^{(i)}-\hat{y}_\delta^{(i)}$ for which I would have an empirical distribution for when considering all $i$. By studying this distribution I could then get a feeling for the relative importance of each of my explanatory variables. Two things I would like some input on:

1. Is the method of performing inference sensible?
2. Should I calculate $\epsilon$ using the above difference or $\epsilon = \hat{y}-\hat{y}_\delta$ where $\hat{y}_\delta = f(x_1,...,x_k,...,x_p)$ i.e. the change with respect to the model prediction rather than the actual value of the output, at the reference values of all the explanatory variables?

Comment: To obtain the VI of one feature, you could train your model once and then permute/scramble one feature of your design matrix and compute the predictions for each permutation. You can then do something like compare the average MSE among your permuted prediction minus the MSE at the unpermuted dataset. You probably want to use the cross-validated predictions. See e.g. this R code/function: https://github.com/tlverse/sl3/blob/devel/R/importance.R

Comment: @LarsvanderLaan ok interesting - I have come across these types of feature importance calculations using permutations before, I guess they give you a sense of which features are important by allowing to rank them and understand their average impact, but I am also interested in the marginal impact of changing one feature - e.g. what is the impact when $x_k: 0 \to 1$?